# calc new pose according to twist

Tags: ros, pose, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any library to do this?
input geometry_msgs::Pose and geometry_msgs::Twist,
output new geometry_msgs::Pose.

I found tf::addDelta(), but it's a little bit different:
/// Starting from a Pose from A to B, apply a Twist with reference frame A and reference point B, during a time t.
geometry_msgs::Pose addDelta(const geometry_msgs::Pose &pose, const geometry_msgs::Twist &twist, const double &t)  **attribute**((deprecated));
and it's deprecated.

so is there any other library to calc new pose according to twist?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214610/calc-new-pose-according-to-twist/) by [rubick](https://answers.ros.org/users/20795/rubick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-07-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming that your Pose and Twist are already in the same reference frame, simply add the linear portion of the Twist to your pose's position.

Then, convert your Pose's orientation to a tf::Quaternion. Store the angular portion of the Twist as a second quaternion using [setRPY()](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Quaternion.html#ab34dfef6a01c1ece07bea92d485b0576) and multiply the two Quaternions together.

---

Originally posted by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) with karma: 194 on 2015-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1